# Bus error when attempting to run Wine under a x86 chroot environment on Raspberry Pi

Tags: x86, arm, cross-platform, chroot, x86-emulation

After following the tutorial at https://www.novaspirit.com/2019/04/15/run-x86-arm/ with a few modifications (I used /x86/ as the chroot directory and installed wine via `apt-get`), attempting to run `winecfg` just returns "Bus Error"

This is being run on a Raspberry Pi 4. The error is so non-descriptive that I've not been able to get anywhere with my troubleshooting attempts.

Here's a complete list of every command I ran to install this:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static binfmt-support debootstrap binutils
sudo mkdir /x86/
sudo debootstrap --foreign --arch i386 stretch /x86 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
sudo mount -t sysfs sys /x86/sys/
sudo mount -t proc proc /x86/proc/
sudo mount --bind /dev /x86/dev/
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /x86/dev/pts/
sudo mount --bind /dev/shm /x86/dev/shm/
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-i386-static /x86/usr/bin/
sudo chroot /x86/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
sudo chroot /x86/ /bin/su -l root
echo "export LANGUAGE='C'" >> .bashrc
echo "export LC_ALL='C'" >> .bashrc
echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
apt update
adduser -uid 1000 pi
apt install leafpad
exit
sudo chroot /x86/ /bin/su -l pi
echo "export LANGUAGE='C'" >> .bashrc
echo "export LC_ALL='C'" >> .bashrc
echo "export DISPLAY=:01" >> .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
exit
sudo chroot /x86/ /bin/su -l root
apt install wine
exit
sudo chroot /x86/ /bin/su -l pi
winecfg
```

When I try to run `winecfg` or run things with wine, I just receive the error **Bus Error**

Comment: I'd assume that qemu isn't emulating all the details of a real x86 system the way WINE is expecting.  It looks like you're using qemu-user; have you googled to see if WINE on qemu-user is supported, or already known to not work?  According to https://wiki.winehq.org/Emulation, maybe.  If you want to debug WINE and/or qemu, try using `strace` to find out what system calls `winecfg` is making when it raises SIGBUS, or what it just made if that happens because of a (guest) user-space operation.

Answer (score 1):

The qemu binaries from the Raspbian Buster repositories stem from an older source version with an unfortunate set of bugs.

One workaround is to modify your procedure to use `qemu-x86_64-static` and `wine64` with an x86_64 chroot<sup>[1]</sup>.

Alternatively, you can build a newer version of `qemu-i386-user` from source. If you have a Debian Buster x86_64 system, the cross-compilation instructions are as follows:

```sh
git clone git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu.git
cd qemu
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf flex bison libglib2.0-dev:armhf
./configure --cross-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --prefix=$(pwd)/usr --static --target-list="i386-linux-user x86_64-linux-user " --enable-linux-user --disable-system
make && make install
cd usr/bin
for f in *; do mv $f $f-static; done
```

The referenced thread also contains a link to such a build for testing.

<sup>[1]</sup> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=226376&start=72

Comment: Also `apt install ninja-build` to compile more recent versions of QEMU.  Most newer Raspberry Pi models have enough memory to compile it themselves (no longer need cross-compile); the binary provided by this method replaces the one in the `qemu-user-static` package, and the pi may need rebooting after the update (remembering to remount `proc` etc for the `chroot`).  I am however now getting a `page_set_flags` assert fail (and illegal instruction) when I try to run `wine notepad`, so I wonder if we need a known good commit of the `qemu` repository (commit `8011837a` matches the answer date)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the `assert` issue even on commit `8011837a`